# redis-cli setting password from a file

Tags: redis

First I start:

```
redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
```

which does not output anything which is a bit weird.

Then I basically set the password

```
redis-cli "config set requirepass ${password}"
```

Then

```
redis-cli "AUTH ...; hset map aaa bbb"

redis-cli "AUTH ...; shutdown"
```

If i now

```
redis-cli "hget map bbb"
```

I get the output aaa.

So unless you **EXPLICITLY** set the password after each server reboot, or redis-cli shutdown then it will go back to being **unprotected**?

Can someone explain?

I have to `config set requirepass` every time the server starts and/or after the shutdown or it will remain unprotected?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why don't you put it in your `redis.conf`?

Comment: it will be in plain text. i will feed it from a file as of now. which i can protect and change easily.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Can I ask you. So if someone enters the server, and then modifies the config file, sets a different password, or provides their own config file to redis-server then the password used will be different? The level of protection is not great.

Comment: Also, if you do set a password, does that mean every command to redis, has to have the AUTH command supplied?

Comment: Yes, so basically you can kill the server and then start it again without  the password.

Comment: What version of Redis are you running? FYI, as of version 6.0, passwords aren't saved as plain text - only their shasum is stored.

Answer (score 1):

When you reconfigure Redis in runtime with `config set`, that configuration only lives as long as the server is running.

To persist that configuration so that it's used after a restart, use `config rewrite`. `config rewrite` writes modified configurations to your configuration file on disk.

You can find all modified configurations that Redis wrote to the configuration file if you search the file for the comment "Generated by CONFIG REWRITE".